# page_attributes_dropdown_pages_args filter does not work

Tags: filters, pages, dropdown

Tried to add filter hook `page_attributes_dropdown_pages_args` to my website together with `quick_edit_dropdown_pages_args` like below to my functions.php theme file.

```
function admin_page_attributes_meta_filter($dropdown_args, $post=NULL) {
    $dropdown_args['depth'] = 1;
    return $dropdown_args;

}
add_filter( 'page_attributes_dropdown_pages_args', 'admin_page_attributes_meta_filter', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'quick_edit_dropdown_pages_args', 'admin_page_attributes_meta_filter');
```

`quick_edit_dropdown_pages_args` is working, `page_attributes_dropdown_pages_args` - not. Tried to use different dropdown arguments, described in [get_pages](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_pages/) documentation and [wp_dropdown_pages](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_dropdown_pages/) documentation. Tried different options, like changing function arguments: `($dropdown_args, $post)`. I have no idea why there is no way to apply the filter to `page_attributes_dropdown_pages_args` hook.

[image: quick_edit_dropdown_pages_args]

[image: page_attributes_dropdown_pages_args]

Comment: That's a classic editor filter, it won't work for the block editor as it's a completely different UI that shares no inner workings, that dropdown is populated by JS not PHP and doesn't use PHP APIs to get the values